# How can I add a button on top of an image at a specific (bounding-box) position without using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, button, canvas, bounding-box

I am trying to add button(s) on top of an image. From my backend I will be given a bounding-box (x, y, image_width, image_height), which I want to use to place the button at the bounding-box position.

My first try was to use canvas -> draw a rectangle and then add an event listener to get the button. But this method is in my opinion not very clean.

Is there any other way to achieve this without using canvas.

```
....
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); 
ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
....
```

Here's a fiddle which should show my current result
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ExceptionFinder/zy0Lnm7s/)

Edit: Just a small edit, the button position is not constant, it depends on the bounding-box I will be given. It's also not a static image but a livestream, although the image size (640x480) is constant.

**Solution** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ExceptionFinder/zy0Lnm7s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does your backend need to set the button position?  This seems un-ideal, but perhaps there's a good reason for it.  Will the backend provide coordinates relative to the whole document, or a single element?  Does the button need to move over time?

My instinct is to add a `div`, set your image as the div's background, and then place the button in the div at the correct spot.  Are you working in vanilla JS or a framework like React?  This will affect how you'd place the button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The button position depends on the objects seen in the image (it's a livestream). So i cannot hardcode the position. Thats why the bounding-box (objects in the image) will vary, although the image size always stays constant. I am using vanilla js + bootstrap

Comment: OK, I see.  Would this work for you:
- Make a `div` for the video area
- Put the video inside a div that lives in the video area.  This div will automatically resize to the size of the video
- Use the `.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight` JS properties to find the video's size
- Set another div inside THAT one, offset by the right math from the size of the video.

Comment: Hey! I updated my post with a new fiddle. It works now, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Cool!  You got the video size from the frontend.  Looks good!